# Как изменить имя процесса?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для упрощения работы в дальнейшем, хотелось бы изменить имя процесса программы. Как это сделать

Comment: переименовать ехе-файл.

Answer (score 4):

Для Линуксов-Посиксов:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
libc = ctypes.CDLL(find_library('c'))

PR_SET_NAME = 15
PR_GET_NAME = 16

def set_proc_name(name):
    name = name.encode('ascii')
    libc.prctl(PR_SET_NAME, ctypes.c_char_p(name), 0, 0, 0)

def get_proc_name():
    name = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)
    libc.prctl(PR_GET_NAME, name, 0, 0, 0)
    return name.value


name='GG'
set_proc_name(name)
```

Вот как оно выглядит в "списке задач"

```
[eri@eri-macro test]$ python procutiltest.py 
^Z
[1]+  Остановлен    python procutiltest.py
[eri@eri-macro test]$ bg
[1]+ python procutiltest.py &
[eri@eri-macro test]$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  12530 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
  12553 pts/2    00:00:00 GG
  12555 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

Но `ps x` покажет  строку запуска.

```
12553 pts/2    S      0:00 python procutiltest.py
```

И вот, кажется, хороший [модуль с поддержкой Windows и остальных](https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle)